# Install app from SharePoint store via client object model

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

I'm looking for a way, how I can install app from SharePoint store to my site in Office 365 using Client Object Model.

In Object model I found method [Web.LoadAndInstallApp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.loadandinstallapp%28v=office.15%29.aspx). It work if I put app from local computer. But I need to find way how I can install app package from SharePoint Store. 
Or may be alternative way how I can get already installed app packages from current site and put them to another site.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround with using WebRequest. I manually request and parse pages addanapp.aspx and appinv.aspx.

Comment: Please post complete answer and mark it to close the question..

Comment: I used Fiddler to capture the traffic when add an app via site content UI. However there are few instances of appearance of addanapp.aspx and addinv.aspx with different parameters. Can you post what you used that worked for the CSOM script?